# Nissan Maxima (1998) Grinding noise from passenger side - Multiple parts replaced but noise is worse now

Tags: wheel-bearing

My other half and I were on a drive Friday night and we could feel the car start to steer itself and felt a wobbling sensation with a grinding noise soon after that.

My other half pulled over and checked the passenger side tire and it was completely loose. We unfortunately had to drive the rest of the way home because we couldn't afford a tow.

When we got home we saw one of my calipers was bad and the brakes were shot. When he looked at the wheel bearings they were bad too. It was all on the passenger side where the grinding is located now.

Calipers, brakes and wheel bearings were all replaced (both sides) and the grinding noise is even more horrifying than before they were changed.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Welcome to the site @user41741, some background would help. When did you first start having problems, is the sound coming from one wheel, and why were so many parts replaced?

Comment: My other half and I were on a drive Friday night and we could feel the car start to stear itself and felt a wabbling sensation with a grinding noise soon after that. My other half pulled over and checked the passenger side tire and it was completely loose. We unfortunately had to drive the rest of the way home because we couldn't afford a tow. When we got home we saw one of my calipers was bad and the breaks were shot. When he looked at the wheel bearings they were bad too. It was all on the passenger side where the grinding is located now. My boyfriend changed both sides to be safe.

Comment: Now after everything was changed the grinding on the passenger side is absolutely unbearable.

Comment: Welcome Mechanics SE! I've edited the additional information you provided into the main question to make it easier for other users to get all the info.

Comment: Please don't cross post : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/23835/10902

Comment: I didn't know where my original post was posted. I had done it from my browser with no account. Then got this account. Sorry

Comment: @SolarMike - It should have been here in the first place, so: no harm; no foul.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I suggested on the other that it would have been better here.. but the Op seems to have two names...

Comment: I’d make sure the caliper bolts aren’t hitting the rotor at this point usually nissan bolts are longer than others and have a flat washer on the end.

Comment: @SolarMike - No worries. It's sorted now.